# Merge vector layers with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have Shapefiles that contain around 54000 objects and I want to create one layer that contains all objects.
For example, currently, I have this

[image]

I want such a new layer
[image]

I have tried in QGIS the [Extract layer extent](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/layertools.html#extract-layer-extent) tool but it creates a large bounding box in which most areas are not needed.

Comment: Did you really repost your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with qgis menu/ vector geometry / concave nearest neighbor
[image]

and with qgis menu/geoprocessing tool/buffer
[image]